# Highlight specific lines on constant basis

Tags: terminal, syntax-highlighting

Haven't found brief explanation.

I have the output in terminal:

```
[2017-04-06 21:12:28,946] [DEBUG] utils.py:106 [farm.utils] - Collection
[2017-04-06 21:12:28,946] [DEBUG] utils.py:108 [farm.utils] - Inserting content to collection
[2017-04-06 21:11:29,699] [ERROR] utils.py:117 [farm.utils] - Unexpected error during insertion.
```

And I want to highlight row with `ERROR` every time it appears.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe your file through this command:

```
sed '/ERROR/s/\(.*\)/'"$(tput setaf 1)"'\1'"$(tput sgr0)"'/' infile
```

For each line containing `ERROR`, it puts the output of

```
tput setaf 1
```

(terminal escape code for, usually, "red") at the beginning of the line and the output of

```
tput sgr0
```

(reset colour escape) at the end of the line.

These look roughly like this:

```
[[31m[2017-04-06 21:11:29,699] [ERROR] utils.py:117 [farm.utils] - Unexpected error during insertion.^[(B^[[m
```

and are interpreted, hopefully, like

[image]

Notice that your pager might have to be configured to interpret escape sequences properly; for example, for `less`, you need the `-R` option.

Comment: are you talking about piping .bash_profile?
It throws error: `sed: infile: No such file or directory`

Comment: @Snobby Ah, sorry, `infile` is just the name I used for the input file. You have to use the name of your logfile instead, or if you want to use the command in a pipe, you have to skip it completely: `command_that_produces_log | sed '/ERROR/...'`

Comment: ehrmm, that's not exactly the thing. I am wondering if I can define it once and so all further output will be highlighted. In your example, I need to type `command_that_produces_log | sed '/ERROR/...'` each time I need this highlighting, which is not so interesting.

Comment: @Snobby Where do the logs come from? Are they in files? Do you have a tool that produces them and you look at the output directly?

Comment: That are logs from python script. Sorry for confusing you, I am really interested in highlighting logs that produce my python scripts. But I don't want to hardcode this in script, I want to place it only once (thought it's possible to manage .bash_profile somehow).

Comment: @Snobby When exactly do you want the lines to be highlighted? When you look at them with `cat`/`less`? What about editing with vim? Do you want functions like `myless` that do the same as `less`, but highlight the lines?